# please find the difference in that two codes? first code is working but second code was not working

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 import java.util.*;
public class arraylist {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ArrayList list=new ArrayList();//Creating arraylist  
          list.add("Ravi");//Adding object in arraylist  
          list.add("Vijay");  
          list.add("Ravi");  
          list.add("Ajay"); 
          list.add(1);
          //Traversing list through Iterator  
          Iterator itr=list.iterator();  
          while(itr.hasNext()){  
           System.out.println(itr.next());  
          }  
         }  
        }



import java.util.*;
public class arraylist {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         ArrayList<int> al=new ArrayList<int>();  
          al.add(1);  
          al.add(2);  
          al.add(3);  
          al.add(4);  
          for(int obj:al)  
            System.out.println(obj);  
         }  
        }
```

please tell problem

Comment: Use `Integer` instead of `int` like  `ArrayList<Integer>`

Answer (score 2):

You can only use objects as generic type. Not primitives. Change to `Integer` and it will compile:

```
          ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();  
          al.add(1);  
          al.add(2);  
          al.add(3);  
          al.add(4);  
          for(int obj:al)  
            System.out.println(obj);
```